# Google Ads/ Analytics is adding Domain to the end of every URL

Tags: google, google-analytics, google-ads, tracking, ppc

We are running Google Ads campaigns. Our destination URLs are not set up with any tracking parameters on them.

However, in Google Analytics, all of our PPC landing pages have ?https://www.example.com/= at the end of every URL. For example

- Destination URL set in Google Ads: /page-name/
- Analytics shows the landing page is: /page-name?https://www.example.com/=

This is only happening for Google Ads campaigns and we cannot figure out what is causing it.